# How to format input in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to format input text on html, sample input: Hi hello

I like to display the input like this

'Hi','hello',

When I hit enter, single quote with a comma will automatically display.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is then formatted and returned to the input field. You only need an eventlistener, a function that converts the text.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('watch');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      input.value = input.value.split(' ').map(s => `'${s}'`).toString() + ',';
    }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" value="Hi World" id="watch">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `join`

```
const str = "Hi hello";
let output = '';
if(str)
     output = `'${str.split(" ").join("','")}',`;
 console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = 'a b c'
console.log(string.split(' ').map(str => `'${str}'`).toString() + ',')
```